# Powershell doesn't compile .java file into .class file

Tags: java, powershell, file, class, compilation

[This is how my file looks in Sublime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j06LG.png)I am new to Java. I created a HelloWorld.java file using Powershell and now I am trying to compile it with command: `javac HelloWorld.java`
It does not create a class file, I get this in the Powershell:

```
>         HelloWorld.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u02d9'
>      ■p u b l i c   c l a s s   H e l l o W o r l d {
```

And it goes on and at the end shows:

> ```
> 37 errors
> ```

Comment: What editor did you use to write the file? Because it looks like you have an invalid character at the start of the file.

Comment: Windows Powershell

Comment: And to write in the java file i use Sublime text

Comment: Well I suggest you re-edit the file and remove the weird character from the start of the first line.

Comment: But when I open the file there is nothing before "public class". I dont know why powershell shows it like that

Comment: I will edit the post and show you how it looks like in the file

Comment: The unicode character \u02d9 is called dot-above and can be used by some editors as a spacer. I suggest you edit the java file with a decent editor and remove any invalid characters.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you very much! I done some research on setting UTF-8 BOM to UTF 8 and it worked!